# While loop on php doesn't work why?

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzAu8.png)i am working on project CMS with php and one of my **while loops** doesn't work and i cant find why.

i am echo on (td) inside of loop and nothing showed on the page but when i echo outside of while loop it work very well.
i have commentet the loop to see you.
Can you give me some help where i have the problem?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>In Response to</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Approve</th>
            <th>Unapprove</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php     
        $query = "SELECT * FROM comments ";
        $select_comments = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_comments)) {
            $comment_id = $row['comment_id'];
            $comment_post_id = $row['comment_post_id'];
            $comment_author = $row['comment_author'];
            $comment_content = $row['comment_content'];
            $comment_email = $row['comment_email']; 
            $comment_status = $row['comment_status']; 
            $comment_date = $row['comment_date']; 


            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>$comment_id</td>";
            echo "<td>$comment_author</td>";
            echo "<td>$comment_content</td>";
/
            echo "<td>$comment_email</td>";
            echo "<td>$comment_status</td>";

            //THIS IS THE LOOP DOESN'T WORK
            $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $comment_post_id";

            $select_post_id_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_post_id_query)) {
                $post_id = $row['post_id'];
                $post_title = $row['post_title'];

            echo "<td><a href='../post.php?p_id=$post_id'>$post_title</a></td>";
            }


            echo "<td>$comment_date</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='comment.php?approve=$comment_id'>Approve</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='comment.php?unapprove=$comment_id'>Unapprove</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='comment.php?delete=$comment_id'>Delete</a></td>";

            echo "</tr>";

        }
?>

    </tbody>      
</table>






<?php

//approve posts
if(isset($_GET['approve'])){

$the_comment_id = $_GET['approve'];

    $query = "UPDATE comments SET comment_status = 'approved' WHERE comment_id = $the_comment_id ";
    $approve_comment_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    header("Location: comment.php");
}


//unapprove posts
if(isset($_GET['unapprove'])){

$the_comment_id = $_GET['unapprove'];

    $query = "UPDATE comments SET comment_status = 'unapproved' WHERE comment_id =  $the_comment_id ";
    $unapprove_comment_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    header("Location: comment.php");
}

//delete posts
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){

$the_comment_id = $_GET['delete'];

    $query = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE comment_id = {$the_comment_id} ";
    $delete_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    header("Location: comment.php");
}



?>
```

Comment: Do you need to close SQL statements in mysqli? `$query = "SELECT * FROM comments ";` if so there's a missing `;`.

Comment: Line 37, what's the `/` doing? A comment is `//`.

Comment: There is no connection to your database. $connection needs to be initialised

Comment: Also is `post_id` a integer or a string identifier? If so you need to do `WHERE post_id='...';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find the missing part on of my db with the connection.

THNX all you friends :D

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting variable `$row` in your second loop. You should change it eg. to `$subRow` to avoid such situation.

Comment: Not best practice, but it certainly isn't breaking anything. OP never uses `$row` again and it will get reassigned on the next iteration of the loop to the next result set

Comment: i have try to change the variable but , i don't understand why echo dont work

Comment: @albdev `echo` should work just fine but maybe there is something wrong with your query? You are ignoring errors now so that's first thing you should change. Check if `mysqli_query` returns `false` and if so log value from `mysqli_error`.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\include\view_all_comments.php on line 20

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\include\view_all_comments.php on line 20

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\include\view_all_comments.php on line 22

Comment: @albdev did you connect to the database? You need to assign connection link from `mysqli_connect` to your `$connection` variable.

Comment: @albdev but `$connection` is not defined so you didn't configure your connection correctly. Where do you set that variable?

Comment: so that loop is for comment and when i look on admin dashboard in the colon the loop doesn't appear

Comment: <?php      
//two ways to connect the database

$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "cms";

foreach($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key), $value );
}

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

?>

Comment: @albdev is this code in the same file as code from question? And also, do not use constants like this. Just pass database credentials directly to `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: that is the db configuration and i include in the header of the page if i am explain well to you

Comment: @albdev based on error `Notice: Undefined variable: connection` there is something wrong with that and PHP can't see that variable.

Comment: @ElonThan i have added thr image and that echo should appear on the column In Response to ,because all the other thing on that loop work just fine